# Zend Edit form - Cant update existing data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I am trying to build an edit function for this form:

```
class Application_Form_ContactMethodSelected extends Zend_Form{

    public function init()
    { 

        $this->CompanyName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('CompanyName', array('label' => 'Firma', 'required' => true));

        $this->submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $this->submit->setLabel('Fertig');

        $this->addElements(array($this->CompanyName,$this->submit));

    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
class UploadController extends Zend_Controller_Action{   
    protected $clientTable;
    protected $model;
    protected $id;

    public function init(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isGet())
        {
            $this->id = (int)$request->getParam('id');
        }
        $this->clientTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_ClientTable();
        $this->model = new Application_Model_DbTable_ClientTable();
        $this->formClient = new Application_Form_ContactMethodSelected();

     }

    public function editAction() 
    {
        if($this->id){
            $results = $this->model->find($this->id);
            $data = array();

            //put results into our data array as name => value

            foreach($results as $r)
            {
                $data['CompanyName'] = $r['CompanyName'];

            }

            //populate  form

            $this->formClient->populate($data);

        }

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->isGet())
            {
                $this->id = (int)$request->getParam('id');
            }

            $client =  $this->clientTable->fetchRow(array('ID' =>$this->id));
            if($this->id){$formClientData = $this->_request->getPost();}

                // write to DB

                $client->CompanyName = $request->getPost('CompanyName');


                //if($results){
               // $where = $this->clientTable->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?',$this->id);
                    //$client->update($client,$where);
                //$this->clientTable->update($client, $where);


                //$this->clientTable->update($data, $where);
                $client->save();

               $this->_redirect('client/index');
                exit;
       }

        $this->view->formClient = $this->formClient;    

    }
}
```

I am able to update my first DB entry with `id=0`. 
But then I am requesting `/uploadcontroller/edit?id=2` I am still updating `id=1`.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right way to get values from $results  to $data. What is the output if you var_dump afterwards?

Comment: Poputlate works, but $this->id is null/1

Comment: What I meant was, there's a good chance that the model returns object, not an array. Could you provide output of the $results and/or html form output?

Comment: array(19) { ["CompanyName"]=> string(3) "wad" };

Comment: Full output will be useful ;)

Comment: and this is results: object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)#82 (10) { ["_data":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(23) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["CompanyName"]=> string(3) "wad".....

Comment: Please append this on the question. this is not exactly a readable format. Apologies for being a pain but this is the right way to get best answer fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error in your code.

You are first checking request `isPost()` then again checking request `isGet()` which is failing (as both can't be true at a time) and your `$this->id` variable is not getting initialized. (so wrong record is updated)

```
if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isGet())
    {
        $this->id = (int)$request->getParam('id');
    }
    .....
```

just get rid of the request `isGet()` condition and use `id` parameter right away.

Sample code:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
    $this->id = (int)$this->_request->getParam('id');
    $client =  $this->clientTable->fetchRow(array('ID' =>$this->id));
    .....
```